# Is this a correct Type 1 grammar?

Tags: chomsky-hierarchy

The task was to give a type 1 grammar(can't be of type 2) which accepts the following words:
baaaab, abb, abba(ab)^i for all i ∈ ℕ

and doesn't accept these words: aabb, bba, bbabb(baaa)^i for all i ∈ ℕ

My solution:

S -> V | W
V -> a B B
W -> W W | A B | B A
A B -> A A B
B A -> B A A
A -> a
B -> b

Example for baaaab:
S -> W -> W W -> B A W -> B A A B -> B A A A B -> B A A A A B -> b a a a a b -> baaaab

Comment: No. S -> W -> B A -> ba

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Sorry i misread the question

Comment: okay, no worries